# Podio: Domain registered does not match the redirect uri

Tags: api, podio, authorize

I was implementing the Podio server-side flow authentication. I used the following url format:

```
https://podio.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=MY-ID&redirect_uri=http://182.35.36.7:8000/authorize/callback
```

It was working when I was in localhost. But it retrieves an error while implementing in live server. The error is:

> The domain registered does not match the redirect_uri given
> (http://182.35.36.7:8000/authorize/callback)

In the podio developers settings I created a key with MY-ID and in the domain I used: `182.35.36.7:8000`

I created another one for localhost with MY-ID-localhost and in the domain I used: `localhost:8000`

I need to add that 182.35.36.7 `(it's not the real ip)` is an internal IP only accesible from the local network or by VPN. But the app accusing to this kind of authentication is not public, and it's only working from the local network.

So the url of the redirection, is http://182.35.36.7:8000/authorize/callback from the local network and it's that url that I want to redirect, but I get the error not matching with the redirect_uri given...

I think the error is redirecting to a local network address. I have no public address to redirect. What I should do in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I made it work, in the podio developers settings I changed the domain from `182.35.36.7:8000` to `182.35.36.7`, once the port is not in the configuration the redirect uri works as desired.